# Getting available date intervals with overlapping busy times

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime-conversion

I'm trying to get available date intervals from a predefined available dates and busy times.

Table of possible dates (slots)

> | ID | SLOT_BEG | SLOT_END |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 11/10/2021 09:00:00 | 11/10/2021 09:15:00 |
> | 2 | 11/10/2021 09:15:00 | 11/10/2021 09:30:00 |
> | 3 | 11/10/2021 09:30:00 | 11/10/2021 09:45:00 |
> | 4 | 11/10/2021 09:45:00 | 11/10/2021 10:00:00 |

Busy times

> | ID | MEET_BEG | MEET_END |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 11/10/2021 09:00:00 | 11/10/2021 09:15:00 |
> | 2 | 11/10/2021 09:32:24 | 11/10/2021 09:46:00 |

Desired result:

> | ID | SLOT_BEG | SLOT_END |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | 11/10/2021 09:15:00 | 11/10/2021 09:30:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1dad29893269ed1b6922f19be0ccc0d0)*

I'm unable to find a way to handle the overlapping cases like `meet ID 2` - it needs to block 2 slots because the starting date is not aligned.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists` with a subquery testing if the invervals do overlap

```
select * from T_TMP_SLOT s
where not exists (
  select null from T_TMP_MEET m
  where  not (s.SLOT_END <= m.MEET_BEG or m.MEET_END <= s.SLOT_BEG)
  );

        ID SLOT_BEG            SLOT_END           
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         2 11.10.2021 09:15:00 11.10.2021 09:30:00
```

Note that the intervals **do not** overlap if the *slot* end before (or equal) begin of *meeting*  `OR` if the *meeting* ends before (or eq) *slot* begin.

So make a *negation* of this predicate to get *overlapping* meetings and check with `not exists` that such meetings do not exists..